# What is the relation between Sharing setting on the tenant level and the Sharing setting inside the site collection level

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-users, sharing

I am a bit confused if there are any relation between the 2 sharing options:-

1. Sharing on the tenant:-

[image]

2. Sharing on the site collection:-

[image]

Is the sharing on the tenant covers only sharing to external users? while sharing on the site collection is applicable for both Internal and external? for example in my above settings, members can share files with internal users , but they can not do so for external? 
and is there any overlap between these settings? or each one covers separate area? is there some scenarios where one setting will override the other ?

Comment: tenant level is the whats and hows, the site collection level is who

Comment: @Mike but is the tenant level the whats and hows for internal users also? as the tenant level settings seems for external users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tenant permissions supersede the site collection. If you don't share outside your organization at the tenant level, then the site collection setting will restrict who can be invited to members of your organization.

Comment: and if i allow sharing contents with external users at the tenant level, and i prevent sharing inside the site collection, then  i will end up restricting sharing with external users to admin users only (or users who have "manage permission" permission level).. is this correct ? i mean if on the tenant level i allow sharing with anonymous users, while on site collection level i prevent members from sharing + i un-check the access request checkbox, then member users will not be able to share with internal and external ,, but admin users can share with internal and external is this correct?

Comment: i believe this is correct

Comment: the problem the sharing settings in Office 365 is really hard to understand ... many level and many options, and i can not find a well documented material which describe real cases....

Comment: i don't know if you are familiar with the server permission structure, but the tenant permissions are more or less equivalent to the web application permissions. So you set them for the least restrictive option that is likely to be used and then use the site collection settings to manage each site. There shouldn't be many tenant admins as that is a level of control that should be highly restricted (there's just too much that can be changed at that level).

Comment: but i am not talking about the site collection sharing settings, which are somehow limited, i am taking about the Sharing settings for external users that is found on the tenant level... there are many concepts that interchange with other such as Share, Get Links, copy Link, Link types...

Comment: The tenant settings are what is _allowed_, the site collection settings cannot override the tenant. **Ex. 1** In the image you posted, only people from your organization can access **any** site collection on the tenant, the site collection has the sharing links set up to allow the link to be forwarded to anyone inside the organization (meaning anyone in the org can open the link). In this scenario, anonymous access at the site collection is the same thing b/c the Tenant will not allow access from outside the org.

Comment: **Ex. 2** If the tenant were set up to allow External Auth and anonymous links, the site collection settings will then be given the same choices as the tenant with regards to who can access the individual site collections. So a Collection1 could be restricted to internal and Collection2 could allow anonymous sharing. **TL/DR** The tenant needs top allow external if you want the option to exist on a Site Collection. [External Sharing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off-for-sharepoint-online-6288296a-b6b7-4ea4-b4ed-c297bf833e30) check out all 3 tabs.

Comment: ok thanks so usually we need to allow external sharing on the tenant, because usually we will have one site collection which need external sharing. but since we allow external sharing on the tenant, so we need to prevent external sharing on the site collection levels... is this correct? so saying "the tenant permissions supersede the site collection" is not 100% correct, as our tenant might allow external sharing, but on the site collection we can prevent external sharing...

Comment: Correct. Tenant supercedes in regards to restriction. A site collection cannot ALLOW more than the tenant but it can RESTRICT more.